# index.html is not directly placed under dist folder after running ng build

Tags: angular, angular6

For an angular version 6 application, I ran command `ng build` and it generated **dist** folder successfully. But my index.html is not directly located under **dist**
The directory structure looks like **dist/project_name/index.html**. What do I need to change to get the *index.html* directly under dist folder.

I need this path for expressjs code and want it to be generic and not contain the project name.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For angular 6 app, try to set "outputPath": "dist" in your angular.json